# How to move a cell between 2 sections with a Button?

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, sections

In my iOS app, I'm trying to move a cell from one section which uses an array (dataArray) to another section which uses another array (followedArray) with a button within each cell. I have the button set up but can't find any code to move cells with a button action.

I tried adding some code to add and remove objects from a NSMutableArray but I got an error

---

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'

---

**Code goes in -(void)followButtonClick:(id)sender**

Here is the code I tried adding to my button that goes in each cell by a tag since I get my arrays from a server and not manually typed in.

```
     [myTableView beginUpdates];

     // Removing Cell from dataArray Section
    [dataArray removeObject: indexPath];
    NSInteger rowToRemove = indexPath.row;
    [myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToRemove inSection:1], nil] withRowAnimation:YES];

    // Inserting Cell to followedArray Section
    [followedArray insertObject:indexPath atIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger rowToAdd = indexPath.row;
    [myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToAdd inSection:0], nil] withRowAnimation:YES];

    [myTableView endUpdates];
```

---

I'm sure this is wrong on many levels, but I'm drawing a blank here. Hopefully someone can point me to the right direction.

**Code:**

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
// Configuring the cell
Data * dataObject;
if (!isFiltered) {

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        dataObject = [followedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else {
        dataObject = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
else {
    dataObject = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

cell.followButton.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.followButton addTarget:self action:@selector(followButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.followButton.hidden = NO;
```

**Follow Button Click within each cell**

```
-(void)followButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender {

// Adding row to tag
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.myTableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

// Creating an action per tag
if (indexPath != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Current Row = %@", indexPath);

    // Showing Status Labels
    CustomCell *cell = [self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.firstStatusLabel.hidden = NO;
    cell.secondStatusLabel.hidden = NO;

    // Change Follow to Following
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"follow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.followButton.hidden = YES;
    cell.followedButton.hidden = NO;

    // ----- ERROR HERE -----
    [self.myTableView beginUpdates];

    // ----- Inserting Cell to Section 0 ----- *NOT WORKING*
    [followedArray insertObject:[gamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] atIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger rowToAdd = indexPath.row;
    [self.myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToAdd inSection:0], nil] withRowAnimation:YES];

    // ----- Removing Cell from Section 1 ----- *WORKING*
    [gamesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger rowToRemove = indexPath.row;
    [self.myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToRemove inSection:1], nil] withRowAnimation:YES];

    [self.myTableView endUpdates];
  }
}
```

*filteredArray* is for my search bar, items are filtered from dataArray.

*dataArray* is where all my data is at from my server

*followedArray* is where I want to put the cell when the button is clicked from *dataArray* or *filteredArray*.

If you need more code, let me know, hopefully I can get this resolved, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what helped me fix the errors, Credits to @AliOmari & @Rachel

```
    [self.myTableView beginUpdates];

    [followedArray insertObject:[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] atIndex:0];
    [myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger rowToRemove = indexPath.row;
    [self.myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToRemove inSection:1], nil] withRowAnimation:YES];

    [self.myTableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete cell from one section, and insert the cell in another section.

```
//update data Array1
[xxx removeObject:xxx];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToRemove inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:YES];

//update data Array2
[xxx insertObject:xxx];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToAdd inSection:0]] withRowAnimation: YES];
```

Comment: I'm getting an error for insertObject: , "No visible @interface for NSArray declares the selector insertObject:"

Comment: @BroSimple  NSArray is not mutable, that's why you cannot modify it. You can use NSMutableArray. examples below:

[anArray removeObjectAtIndex: index];
[anArray removeObject: item];
[anArray removeLastObject];

Comment: Okay so I made it a NSMutableArray, and I used [followedArray insertObject:indexPath atIndex:0]; is this correct and also one more thing, for indexPathForRow: rowToRemove or rowToAdd, where do I use this? I'm fairly new sorry

Comment: I can't figure out what to do with rowToRemove and rowToAdd, I figured out the rest but stuck on what you said with those

Comment: @BroSimple here *rowToRemove* and *rowToAdd* are the original index of   your data source. For instance, your original dataArray is, ["apple", "banana", "orange"], and now you want to remove "banana", so here rowToRemove: is 1 (index starts from 0); then its indexPath is [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]. does this make sense to you?

Comment: @BroSimple  also, if you already know the indexPath of the rows that you gonna to delete/add, then you can just use the indexPath there directly. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I updated the follow button code with what you told me and the help from other programmers here but I'm getting an error when inserting the object to another array/section. Same error but instead of "insert row 1" its "row 0" Any help?